# How to implement the clear Button Functionality for Edittext that are same as calculator?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am going to Implement the Calculator type application in my application.
I have successfully implement the all functionality.
Buit stuck with the lastSingle character clear button that is available as "C" on any other calculator.
So i need code to implement it.
So if any one have it then please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: what the problem you facing? what you have to do upto for this?

Comment: I want the code for the single character clear button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void clear(){

String text = (yourEditText.getText().toString);
if(!(text.equals("")))
yourEditText.setText(text.subString(0,text.length-2));
}
```

a better one could be

```
Editable editableText = yourEditText.getEditableText();
            int length = editableText.length();
            if (length > 0) {
                editableText.delete(length - 1, length);
            }
```

Comment: but if you want to delete something from particular position it will not help i think

Comment: Ok Second one works fine for me. Thanks. Now have u any idea to implement that "." functionality ? i mean to to use the Floting point with the "." button pressed, same as calculator ??

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo code for, how to create calculator in Android, this also have the clear function key implemented in it, study it to use it

LInk http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/nookdevs/com/nookdevs/calculator/Calculator.java.htm

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is what I have done

It will help you in all the ways i.e. location deletion and non location deletion of elements from edit text

```
private void handleBackspace() {

        String txt = _txtGiven.getText().toString();
        String value = "";
        int i = _txtGiven.getSelectionStart();
        for (int j = 0; j < txt.length(); j++) {
            char c = txt.charAt(j);
            if (!((i - 1) == j)) {
                value += c;
            }
        }
        if (txt.length() == 1 && i == 1) {
            _txtGiven.setText("");
        }
        if (value.length() > 0) {
            _txtGiven.setText(value);
            if (!(i == 0)) {
                _txtGiven.setSelection(i - 1);
            }
        }

}
```

where _txtGiven is your edit text

Use this code and let me know if you face any problem

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

When you press the 'C' button on the windows calculator you get : '0.'.

Two options :

```
EditText et = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

or

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
```

then

```
et.setText("0.");
```